# Ektron form post back message customizing

Tags: forms, ektron

Can we add custom post back message for Ektron form?

I have selected Blank Form with DxH Mapping and add my custom text boxes . Then the postback message is added as Like [this](http://documentation.ektron.com/cms400/v802/mobile_help/Advanced/Content/Managing%20Content/HTML%20Forms/ewe400%20forms%20creating%20new.htm),[image]

**any idea how to add custom post back message?**

Comment: Um... that's where you do it. The big WYSIWYG editor there. Or, if you've already added the form, one of the tabs along the top when editing will give you the same option as here. So where do you need help?

Comment: My problem is when I send form, there is chace to fail send data to mapped dx hub. So I want the currect postback status message. When Iam testing the dxh form I got exact result.but if I run the real form i cant customize it. Please any help?

Comment: So you want multiple post back messages and display a different message based on different conditions?

Comment: yes almost like that,is that possible?

Comment: If you want to use DXH data in your form postback, you may not be able to do so because the data is submitted to the DXH asynchronously. Meaning that the form doesn't wait for the submission to the DXH to succeed/fail. This makes sure that, if there is a problem with the DXH, your users' experience does not suffer.

You could use the submitted form data in your postback message. For instance, if you had a Name field in your form, then your postback message could say "Thank you, Nikhil!..."

Try to describe exactly what you want to achieve and I'll try to help.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20400321/can-i-customise-the-post-back-message-in-ektron-html-form-with-the-message-retur

Answer (score -1, accepted):

DXH post back message is submitted asynchronously so you cannot customize the post back message.